# Android set Color component (R, G, B)

Tags: android, colors, variable-assignment

I want to create a Color variable to reference its qualities except I only seem to be able to get the R, G, B int values, I can't figure out how to set each one individually.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
private int ReturnColor(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
    return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
}

if (ReturnColor(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) == Dawn) Then...
```

Where Dawn would be a Color, I guess I could make a custom class but I was hoping there was a more straight forward method.

EDIT: I ended up just creating a custom class with a int A, R, G and B variable.

```
public class CustomColor {

int A;
int R;
int G;
int B;

public CustomColor() {}

public CustomColor(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
    A = a;
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;  
}

private int ReturnColor(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
    return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
}

public boolean EqualTo(CustomColor c) {

    if(A == c.A && R == c.R && G == c.G && B == c.B) return true;
    return false;
}

}//End CustomColor
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some static colors declared in the Color class like `Color.WHITE`

if you want to make up your own colors you can use 0xFFFFFFFF
the first FF is alpha, the second is red, the third is green and the last is blue

i.e.

> CYAN = 0xff00ffff;